# не работает функция get_current_dir_name на языке программирования Си

Tags: c

Помогите пожалуйста , мне нужно определить полный путь до исполняемого файла программы . В интернете нашел , что это можно реализовать с помощью ф-ции get_current_dir_name (тут нашел - http://all-ht.ru/inf/prog/c/func/get_current_dir_name.html) , но представленный код не работает [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста исправить эту ошибку .

```
    #include <unistd.h>  //Для get_current_dir_name
#include <stdio.h>   //Для printf

int main (void)
{    
   // Переменная, в которую будет помещен указатель 
   // на область памяти с путем к текущей директории 
   char *DirName;

   // Определяем путь к  текущей директории 
   DirName = get_current_dir_name ();

   // Выводим путь в консоль
   printf ("Текущая директория: %s\n" ,DirName);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `get_current_dir_name()` определена только если есть определение `_GNU_SOURCE`

Нужно добавить

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE  
#include <unistd.h>
```

и а так как `get_current_dir_name()` выделяет память, нужно ее после использования высвободить.

```
free(DirName);
```

не все компиляторы поддерживают функцию `get_current_dir_name()`, можно воспользоватся другими функциями `getcwd()` например.

```
char * dir_name = NULL;
dir_name = getcwd(NULL, 0);
if (dir_name != NULL) {
    printf("Current dir : %s\n", dir_name);
    free(dir_name);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Подскажите free(DirName); нужно добавить после вызова переменной DirName (после printf) или в другое место кода? Я добавил #define _GNU_SOURCE   #include <unistd.h> , но все равно выдает ошибку , ошибке такие же как и на скрине.

Comment: В Вашем случаи, добавить `free(DirName)` нужно после `printf()`  Ваш компилятор должен поддерживать стандарт POSIX  ,что бы использовать эту функцию